# Maintaining center alignment

Tags: html, css

If I have a div tag.

```
<div id="length"></div>
```

I want its contents centered. I also want the width of the div to be decreased(enough to hold a number).

```
  #length{

  background:black;
  color:white;
  border:3px solid grey;
  width:35px;
  //margin-left:655px;// Currently I am using this to center.
  border-radius:50%;

}
```

But if I alter the width property, it loses the center alignment. Is there a way to do this without losing the center alignment??

Comment: Provide a link to a live example. There are many solutions that can address this problem, but we can't suggest the right one without a better prospective of the whole picture (markup structure and placement of elements in relation to each other).

Comment: http://codepen.io/jpninanjohn/pen/JKoYqR   . Its for a simon game. The div in question displays the number of the patternLength.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
margin:0 auto;
```

Should keep your content in the centre

Answer (score 0):

You can try tho use the auto margin for your div. Have a try to

```
margin: 0 auto;
```